# Meaning of "if not" in a sentence

Tags: grammar, word-usage, meaning-in-context

I don't understand the meaning of "if not" and grammar of the sentence in bold:

> As early as the 14th century, the organ supplied polyphony, in which
> case the odd-numbered verses of text were omitted altogether. This
> role for the organ grew steadily in importance in the late
> Renaissance.
>
> Until the middle of the 17th century, **organ versets
> were based on the chants they replaced, thus invoking if not
> presenting the appropriate words.** During the next hundred years this
> large organ literature made little reference to a cantus firmus,
> reaching its artistic zenith and liturgical nadir in France.

[Source: The Harvard Dictionary of Music' By Don Michael Randel]

Comment: You've only bolded a segment of **one sentence**.

Comment: @Chappo Thanks for mention. Can you please tell me whats that mean?

Comment: I think the original text needs some commas:  *"organ versets were based on the chants they replaced, thus invoking, if not presenting, the appropriate words"* - this is much easier to parse.

Answer (score 2):

This turned out to be a bit more complicated to explain than I had anticipated, so I can understand the reason to post your question on ELU! The combination of "if not", "invoking" (which lends a sense of something not present) and "presenting" (i.e. being present) takes some unravelling…

**if not** - [ODO](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/if-not?q=if%20not):

> Perhaps even (used to introduce a more extreme term than one first
>   mentioned):
>   *'hundreds if not thousands of germs'*

**invoke** - [ODO](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/invoke):

> 2.2 Give rise to; evoke:
>   *'how could she explain how the accident happened without invoking his wrath?'*

So, your bolded portion could be reworded as:

> organ versets replaced the chants, but as they were based on the words
>   of the chants, the versets evoked [gave a sense of] the words without
>   actually presenting them.

Answer (score 1):

**If not**, in gerneral terms represents a more extreme term than the former (in this case 'invoking'). Organ chants were based on the chants they replaced, thus invoking **perhaps even** presenting the appropriate words.

In this case, 'presenting' is more extreme than 'invoking' the appropriate words.

For example: Let's meet up tonight if not sooner ([link](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/if+not)).