# Dual meaning of "good, if not great"

Tags: meaning

Example sentence: Alice is a good, if not great, dancer.

I notice people interpret this sentence in two ways:

1. Alice is a good dancer, but she's not great.
2. Alice is a good dance. Actually, that's an understatement, she's a great dancer.

The first interpretation is my first reaction, but the second one is plausible as well. Is context the only way to distinguish between these two interpretations? For my purposes quite often there is no context available however. I am looking for help with how to interpret this expression in these situations.

Comment: She's good, and she may even be great.  The determination has not been made yet.

Comment: Another question on this: https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/400428/if-not-unorthodox-usage

Comment: When spoken, the interpretation depends on the stress pattern.

Comment: Besides context, when speaking, there’s intonation.   Which could be lumped in to “context”.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Most of the time it is meant as a measured praise. (Your 2nd reading)
But there is enough wiggle room in this phrase to make it context-sensitive. It could possibly be turned into a backhanded compliment.

Comment: Yes, that construction is inherently ambiguous in writing. In speech, of course, it can be made unambiguous either way with intonation.